# Integrating maven changes plugin with Jira agile

Tags: maven, jira, jira-agile, maven-changes-plugin

We have recently migrated to jira agile and the issues have changed from tasks bugs to stories. We have been using maven changes plugin to automatically send notification for new releases and it successfully includes issues resolved and so on. Now that we have stories, it does not include them to the message body. I have updated the configuration properties to include stories also and all possible issue types (Bug, New Feature, Task, Improvement, Sub-task,Story) but still no success. The jira report that is generated by the same plugin is correct but the mail still does not include them.

I also tried to attach the jira report (${basedir}/target/site/jira-report.html) but with no success.

Can anyone propose a solution or a work around too this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some further research and a lot of code checking in the source code of maven changes plug-in I found out that you have to include the following mapping in your configuration

```
            <issueTypes>
                <add>Story</add>
                <fix>Bug</fix>
                <update>Task</update>
            </issueTypes>
```

This will inform the maven changes plug-in to map the build in xsd add,fix,update to Story, Bug, Task issues that are created with agile jira